# Delegate between TableViewController and ParentViewController it is embedded in?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

Is there a way to execute a delegate outside of didSelectForRowAtIndexPath?

I have a delegate between my cells and my TableViewController, and I want a delegate between my TableViewController and it's parent when an array.count is a certain number.

Here is my protocol:

```
protocol DepressedTableViewControllerDelegate {
func sendToParent(controller:DepressedTableViewController, arrayOfChoices: Array<Int>!, proceed: Int!)
}
```

Here is the delegate between the TableViewCell and the TableViewController

```
func filledOut(controller: DepressedTableViewCell, selections: Int!, isClicked: Bool!) {
    doTheDelegate() 
    choices.append(selections)
    if isClicked == true {
        advanceArray.append(1)
    }
    if advanceArray.count == 4 {
        isItReady = true;
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to do something like this:

```
func doTheDelegate() {
    if isItReady == true {
        if delegate != nil {
            delegate?.sendToParent(controller: self, arrayOfChoices: choices, proceed: advanceArray.count)
            print("this happened")
        }

    }
}
```

Where should I put this so it will actually send the data to my parent controller? I've tried putting it in almost every method and nothing works.

I can't do didSelectForRowAtIndexPath, because, though buttons in the cells are interacted with, the cells themselves remain unselected.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask. Are you trying to notify the parent about some user action? If so, what action? It looks like you're trying to make the cells trigger a method in the table view controller that keeps track of the number of "clicked" actions (whatever that means), and after you have 4 clicked events, you want subsequent cell actions to trigger your message to the parent view controller. It looks like your code should do something. It isn't clear how that something fails to meet what you want.

Comment: Yeah, basically when advanceArray.count == 4, I want to make a button appear on the parent view controller. Nothing is working though.

Comment: And? What does your code do/not do?

Comment: It won't even call the delegate

Comment: You're gonna have to provide a lot more info than that.

Comment: So I've been doing some testing, and it looks like in my TableViewController my delegate is returning nil for some reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129672/discussion-between-zy-mazza-and-duncan-c).